# Removing default border around an image - Chrome browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I can't believe I ran on this problem for the first time. I have searched lot of other similar question on SO regarding the same issue, but none of them worked for me.

I have a img tag with a class attribute under anchor tag.

So my html looks like:

```
<ul id="racing-menu" class="accordion-menu list-unstyled">
  <li>
    <a id"something" name class"something">
      <img class="icon_71">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.icon_71 {
  background: url(../../cms/images/sports/something.png) no-repeat;
  width: 36px;
  height: 22px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  float: left;
}
```

I tried the following solutions in order to avoid default border on Chrome browser

1)border: 0
2)outline: none
3)changing img class to img id

4)Setting

```
a img {
  border:none
} 

a img {
  border:0
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your `<img>` tag does not have a `src` attribute since you are setting background with css.

```
<img class="icon_406">
```

This is invalid html - if you intend to implement icons through css use `<span>` or something similar that does not require `src` attribute by specification. Or load the image icons through `src` attribute of `<img>` element.

Chrome displays a border since it cannot find the image (same as if the `src` had a broken link inside) - but the icon shows since css is still able to apply the class styling to the empty `<img>` element.

Comment: great. I replaced the img tag to span in my JS and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: @Nish - I believe you :) - Accept answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: "Chrome displays a border since it cannot find the image" that was a key statement. Indeed I just added image in the code and borders now are gone

Answer (score 5):

Replace IMG tag width DIV, and it should work :)

Comment: as you can see in my original post. I have already tried that solution.

Comment: I tried this on your site, using google developer toolbar and worked like a charm :) 
Here's a screenshot:
http://i.imgur.com/iK57iFG.png

Comment: My mistake. I thought you wanted to say replace <img class""> with <img id""> My mind was occupied :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace **'a img'** with just **'a'**.

Means add the following css:

```
a img {
  border: none;
}
```

You can also try some bad stuff to test if the border is the problem:

```
* {
   border: none !important;
}
```

**But i don't recommend the second code because it may generate other issues, the second code is just thaught to test if the border is the problem.**

Comment: this didn't work. However replacing img to span tag worked fine since I was showing image through CSS not with src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<img>`, but set the `src` property to an empty string.

```
// Get an HTMLImageElement anyway you want.
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(function(img) {
  // This can also be used to abort an image load.
  img.src = '';
});
```

Tested in Chrome only.