# How to remove border from image in chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a web application with an image tag which has a css class but **no** **`src`** attribute. Something like this:

```
<img class="image"/>
```

The css class just defines the url of the image and its size but no border properties are defined. The problem is that a white border is being rendered for the image **only in chrome browser** (it works fine in firefox and IE11). I've tried to remove it explicitely through css rules but until now I can't.

A solution is to set the url of the image through the `src`attribute but I have too many images which take their source from css rules. So, is there any way to remove that white border from css? Maybe is that a chrome bug?

This issue is happening to me from few days ago. It seems it comes with the last update of chrome.

[Here you have a jsfiddle to test what I say.](https://jsfiddle.net/yoqpnu2z/)

And here you have directly the same code snippet of the jsfiddle example:

```css
body {
   background-color: brown;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;   
  }
  
  .image {
   background-image: url("http://www.ultimatedesignertoolkit.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/preview1.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 600px 400px;
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   height: 400px;
   padding: 0;
   position: relative;
   top: 5px;
   vertical-align: top;
   width: 600px;
  }
```

```html
<div>
    <img class="image"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013071/removing-the-image-border-in-chrome-ie9

Comment: have you try `div img[class="image"] { border: none;}`

Comment: That's not how the `<img>` tag should be used, you'll get the broken image icon in a lot of browsers, since there is no src set, this is what I see - http://i.imgur.com/SmlwXzl.png

Comment: Any reason you're not using a `div` for the task?

Comment: this may not be the valid markup and you can use div instead of img without src. You may see the browser compatibility issues too.

Comment: @JNF no reasons for use `img` instead `div`. It's just it was made by this way lot time ago. But I've seen in all the comments and answers that's no correct so I'm going to replace all images with no `src` attribute with `div` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you set image as background to the `img` tag? You should use the `src` attribute (which is required to have valid html) to define the image url.

```
<img class="image" src="http://www.ultimatedesignertoolkit.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/preview1.png"/>
```

If that is not possible for some reason, consider using `div` instead of `img` to achieve the same effect.

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

please check the accepted answer: [Removing default border around an image - Chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096860/removing-default-border-around-an-image-chrome-browser)

"Chrome displays a border since it cannot find the image"

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using an `img` tag with no `src` attribute. Chrome is essentially indicating the size of the container with nothing in it.

```css
body {
  background-color: brown;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;   
}
  
.img {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 600px 400px;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://www.ultimatedesignertoolkit.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/preview1.png"/>
</div>
```