# How to remove the border of an image?

Tags: html, css

I have founded many question like mine on StackOverflow [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153425/how-remove-border-around-image-in-css)  [example2](http://html.com/images/borders-and-image-links/) but for a unknown reason I still have some borders displayed around my image:

[image]

```
 .imgCadenas{
  width:  50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url('/cadenas.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  background-size: 100%;

  border:0;
  border-style: none;

  position: absolute;
  right: 150px;
  top: 5px;
}
```

Someone has a solution ?

[EDIT] with your advices I have this CSS in the browser:
[image]

```css
.liMachine {
    list-style-type: none;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    word-break: break-all;
    position: relative;

}

.imgCadenas{
  width:  50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/256/sign-check-icon.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  background-size: 100%;

  border: 0 !important;
  border-style: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
  display: block;

  position: absolute;
  right: 250px;
  top: 5px;
}

.whoLock{
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<li class="liMachine switch">
        <div id="nameMachine">
            <h3>My machine</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="stateMachine">
            State:<span class="state">running</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img class="imgCadenas">
            <p class="whoLock">Locked by: StackOverflow</p>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: `display: block;`? I believe that fixes unwanted borders.

Comment: add `outline: none; border: none`

Comment: May be the image has that border? @Jerome

Comment: If the border isn't coming from the background image itself then Pugazh methods should apply, if not - then it's very possible that whatever rule you are trying to declare to negate this border style is being overwritten or overqualified by another rule - which should be easy enough to identify in your browser IDE/development tool pop-up.

Comment: outline: none; border: 0 none;. Please check and see if there is a border in  image.

Comment: `border: 0`, `outline: none`, `box-shadow: none`, `background-color: transparent`, or even the image has the border itself, ... there are too many options :(

Comment: Richard: it didn't change anything. Pugazh it didn't change anyhting. ThisBeliever no it didn't. UncaughtTypeError in the console I can see my parameters and they aren't overwrittent. Mukeysh nothing has changed, Diego arrrrg

Comment: Yea... like Diego and others, I'm wondering if the border is part of the image, can you confirm it's not Jerome?

Comment: So let me try with an other image

Comment: I confirm it NOT the image

Comment: Could you show the corresponding HTML?

Comment: Did you have the website url? or can you paste the code to jsfiddle?

Comment: @SLWS I added a Snippet.  Jkythc I made a fiddle because for the moment in in Localhost

Comment: Your img element missing src attribute, this is the Chrome browser issues. You need to add back the src attribute.

Comment: @jkythc but I want to set it with the CSS, it's not possible ?

Comment: @Jerome Use another element, e.g. div

Comment: @jkythc it works ! can you put an answer ? And I'll upvote the others because it's right, just not with Chrome

Comment: @Jerome My answer updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify like this:

```
.imgCadenas{
  width:  50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url('/cadenas.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  background-size: 100%;

  border: 0 !important;
  border-style: none !important;
  outline: none !important;

  position: absolute;
  right: 150px;
  top: 5px;
}
```

**EDITED**

Your `img` element missing `src` attribute, 
Try to change `img` element to `div` element.

See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22097004/4964262

Comment: nothing has changed and it's really frustrating because it should change

Comment: Thank you for the help ! Now everything is working fine

Answer (score 1):

This can change on different browsers. You can try `border-style:none !important;`

So for all img:

```
img{border-style:none !important;}
```

or just for your img

```
<img class="imgCadenas" src"">

.imgCadenas{border-style:none !important;}
```

If you send your link for control. I can look for you.

Comment: nothing has changed it's pretty frustrating because it should change

Answer (score 1):

Does adding !important to your CSS remove the border?

Answer (score 1):

Try using.

```
img {
    border:none;
    outline:none
}
```